# Download file using fetch API

Tags: react-native, fetch

I would like download file on React-Native app. The problem is not about React-Native, but i don't know how i can download the `webm` file.

What i've try :

```
  const request = await fetch(
    'https://invidious.ggc-project.de/latest_version?download_widget=%7B%22id%22%3A%22LGdNnnQFg2M%22,%22itag%22%3A%22250%22,%22title%22%3A%22My%2Bthoughts%2Bon%2Ba%2B2nd%2Blockdown,%2Bmostly%2Btalking%2Btrash%2Babout%2BCuomo%2Bwhile%2Briding%2Ba%2Bbike-LGdNnnQFg2M.webm%22%7D'
  );
  const file = await request.blob();

  console.log(file);
```

`file` return `{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "8097cab2-3ee3-4fb0-8525-3f50839b3c9e", "offset": 0, "size": 8441786}}`.

I don't know how i can download my file. I think i need using library like [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) for write and save file. But i don't know how is the process ^^

Anyone have already download file using fetch API ?

Thank you guys !

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob is provides easy way to download.